# Dynamically set node properties

Tags: node-red

When I have a look at the Properties of a node, I can use dynamic expressions or values for some of them, while others seem to be static (e.g. dropdown values). Consider for example the properties of a debug node:

[image: debug node properties]

While I can define a dynamic expression (i.e. it depends on the node's input) for `Output`, I can't change the `To` checkboxes on a per-message way. I could have created a switch node with all possible choices, but that's not what the question is about and seems like a lot of boilerplate.

If I had a node with a variety of properties where I can't select a message property or JSONata, could I still modify those properties per message without modifying the node's code?

One use-case relates to the many Smart Home integrations, where I could select a device from a dropdown list in an action node's properties. There seems to be no way if I wanted to control certain devices in a dynamical way without having dozends of switch nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the specific node doesn't explicitly offer a way to pass in and override a configured values there is no generic way to change them.